# Does Andrews curve's density in Liquid- Saturated vapor phase change region vary or not?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, phase-transition, kinetic-theory

Are Andrews Curve (isotherms) for gas-liq phase change less dense for low values temperature and more dense for high value of temperature?

[image: andrews curves]

I came up with this because of Clausius Clapeyron Equation with says dP/dT ∝ 1/T. For low values of T change in pressure i.e dP is more and thus the isotherm will be spaced further apart to each other,opposite of what will happen at high temperatures(ofcourse below Critical temperature).

Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a question of reading the diagram it seems to me. For a given mass of gas or vapor, at constant pressure in dark blue region looking like an inverted parabola interior :

when gas condenses volume decreases (green left arrow), so weight/volume of liquid density increases.

when gas evaporates volume increases (red right arrow), so weight/volume of vapor density decreases.

[image]

Comment: I am so sorry my question wasn't presented well.. i wasn't talking about the density of liquid or vapour but the density of andrews curve itself. I mean if we draw andrews curve for every 5K temperature interval i assume that lower isotherms corresponding to low temperature will be spaced from each other more in comparison to upper isotherms. Thus lower isotherms having low density than upper ones. The reason i think this should be true is provided in 2nd para of question. Again, now if i have made it clear enough, what do you think is true? (I have edited the title of 
the question)